# Backup all Ubuntu 12.04 files

Tags: 12.04, backup

If I copy all files from Ubuntu (I guess that it is everything except media folder?) to another partition of my disk/another disk, would I be to restore Ubuntu exactly as it was just by pasting everything? (I want to erase my disk, then install Windows, then install Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

No, you would still have to reinstall. Only backup what is necessary like pictures, video, music, not system files for Ubuntu.

Comment: I know that I have to reinstall, I just want to know if I can somehow keep all my customizations/software on Ubuntu instead of redoing them from scratch.

Comment: I found an article with directions. I think this is what you're looking for.

http://www.matthartley.com/how-to-backup-your-ubuntu-software/